# Maven error while downloading jboss-messaging

Tags: jboss, maven, repository, maven-3

You could see below error that Im getting while compiling an EJB example that I'm trying to run with JBoss AS.

From error I could understand that repository URL specified is wrong. What I'm not getting is how can I find from where this URL is coming? Is this URL in any of the existing POM file in my repository/projects?

Also artifact version is "${version.jboss.messaging}". This is bit strange and I'm not able to find out where this version is specified?

Need some help here.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jboss.ejb3.examples:jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-api:jar:3.1.0-Alpha1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8 (compile), org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-log4j:jar:2.0.6.GA (compile), org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA (compile), org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-openejb-embedded-3.1:jar:1.0.0.Alpha5 (test), org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-junit:jar:1.0.0.Alpha5 (test), org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:3.1.4 (test), javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1 (test), org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-profileservice-client:pom:6.0.0.Final (compile), org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-jbossas-remote-6:jar:1.0.0.Alpha5 (compile), org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-client:pom:6.0.0.M1 (compile)]:

`Failed to read artifact descriptor for jboss.messaging:jboss-messaging:jar:${version.jboss.messaging}:` `Could not transfer artifact jboss.messaging:jboss-messaging:pom:${version.jboss.messaging} from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2):` Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/jboss/messaging/jboss-messaging/${version.jboss.messaging}/jboss-messaging-${version.jboss.messaging}.pom -> [Help 1]

---

This is my repository element in POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-deprecated-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Deprecated Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 5):

Point your [JBoss](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users) Repository to: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ instead of http://repository.jboss.com/maven2

```
 <repository>
    <id>JBoss Repo</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    <name>JBoss Repo</name>
 </repository>
```

Comment: I already have this repository in place. I'm not using "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2" in any of my Maven files.

Comment: [updated answer] Can you clarify what Maven files are you pertaining to? The maven error message says you're pointing at the repository.jboss.com/maven2

Comment: check your settings.xml as well if the mirror is still pointing to the old jboss repo url

Comment: @gouki Nowhere in my Maven installation (even in settings.xml), my repo URL is pointing to old jboss repo URL.